# to get last 20 columns of an image :Matlab

Tags: matlab

i have an image IMG ,i want to get its last (20) colums only.
i-e the image is of size 500x500 and i want the colums starting from 480 to 500 ,number of rows remain same.

Comment: Downvote because: what have you tried, no research effort.

Answer (score 3):

You can put some basic math and the `end` keyword in your indexing.  So you would have

```
smallerImage = rawImage(:,  (end-20+1):end);
```

As a colormapped (NxMx1) example

```
load mandrill;  %A colormapped (2d) Matlab demo image in the X variable
figure;
subplot(121)
image(X)
colormap(map)
title('Full picture')
subplot(122)
smallX = X( : , (end-20+1):end );  %This is the subsetting operation for a 2D image
image(smallX)
colormap(map)
title('Rightmost 20 columns')
```

An RGB example  (NxMx3)

```
imdata = imread('ngc6543a.jpg');
figure;
subplot(121)
image(imdata )
colormap(map)
title('Full picture')
subplot(122)
smallImData = imdata ( : , (end-20+1):end ,  : );  %This is the subsetting operation for an RGB image, note 3rd dimension colon
image(smallImData )
colormap(map)
title('Rightmost 20 columns')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cutImg = img(startrow:endrow,startcol:endcol);
```

Taken from:

[Matlab Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/171209)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take the last `n` columns, use:

```
   A(:,end-n+1:end)
```

For the first `n` columns use:

```
   A(:,1:n)
```